# Typescript Error: Property 'mapType' is missing in type '{}'

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hi i am following a youtube video on how to implement Google Maps into ionic. I have this error that i don't understand. When i run the app i got this error:

Link to video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD5yYX1KWXA

Typescript Error:

Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GoogleMapOptions'. Property 'mapType' is missing in type '{}'.

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {GoogleMap, GoogleMaps, LatLng, CameraPosition, GoogleMapsEvent, MarkerOptions, Marker} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap()
  {
    let element = document.getElementById('map');
    let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element, {});
  }

}
```

The error is pointing at .....(element, {});

i simply can't put {}.

btw im still new to ionic

Comment: You can skip {} as a parameter, according to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/) documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass any option to the map, just omit that parameter like this:

```
  loadMap() {
    let element = document.getElementById('map');
    let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);
  }
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Nothing is wrong omitting the {} right?

Comment: Of course not, since it's a valid way to initialize the map. It will be initialized using the default configuration, but that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

That means, by the author of the typings (TypeScript definition), the `GoogleMapOptions` requires you to specify `mapType`.

The means either:

- it is needed and you need to specify it (e.g. `...create(element, { mapType: 'street' })`, or
- the typings is wrong and the author needs to fix it.

See if `@ionic-native/google-maps` supplies the typings, if not, you should find it in github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped.